# java TwitterAuthClient onActivityResult

Tags: java, onactivityresult, twitter-fabric

I tried to code an auth Twitter in Java via com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter. See below my code :

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.*;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.*;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterCore.*;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.OAuthSigning;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import java.lang.Object.*;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Fragment;
public static void authentificationTwitter() {
    classAuthentificationTwitter auth=new classAuthentificationTwitter();
    auth.execAuthentificationTwitter();
}

public static class classAuthentificationTwitter extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void execAuthentificationTwitter() {
        Log.v("myLog", "authentificationTwitter");    
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        TwitterCore twitter = new TwitterCore(authConfig);    
        Fabric.with(getCurrentActivity(), twitter);
        client = new TwitterAuthClient();
        client.authorize(getCurrentActivity(), new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
                Log.v("myLog", "authentificationTwitter Success");        
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Log.v("myLog", "authentificationTwitter echec");
            }
        });
        //startActivityForResult(getIntent(),99);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.v("myLog", "authentificationTwitter onActivityResult : " + requestCode + " / " + resultCode + " / " + data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (client != null) {
            client.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}


static TwitterAuthClient client;
```

The problem, my callback never called. I read that, it will be fine to modify the onActivityResult method in the main Activity to dispatch the result but I can't access it. I can only modify my proper code.

Somebody may be can help me.
Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S: I'm news in Java ...

Comment: What does `getCurrentActivity()` do? `onActivityResult()` will be called on the `Activity` you pass in `client.authorize(activity, callback)`. Why don't you call `client.authorize(this, callback)`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I use on IDE named Windev mobil, getCurrentActivity is the equivalence to "this".

Comment: Your way of calling `execAuthentificationTwitter()` seems a bit unorthodox for Android. You're calling it from a `static` method which I assume you're calling from another class? If what you're trying to do is to start the authentication as soon as the Activity starts, you should call `execAuthentificationTwitter()` in the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

You need to call onActivityResult inside your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

If the callback inside a fragment. you need to call onActivityResult  in both activity and fragment.
Please check https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter